# Strong parameters in test issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

Ruby 2.1.1p76 on Rails 4.1.1.

Please check out my controller:

```
def update
 begin
  current_user.update_settings user_settings_params unless params[:user_setting].blank?
  current_user.update_attribute :district_id, params[:user][:district_id] unless params[:user].blank? || params[:user][:district_id].blank?
  flash[:success] = "Preferencje zostały zaktualizowane"
  redirect_to subscription_index_path
 rescue UserLevelException => exception
  flash[:alert] = "Sprytnie, za karę zostałeś wylogowany ;)"
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_path
  return
 end
end

private

def user_settings_params
 params.require(:user_setting).permit(
  :inquiry_subject, :inquiry_body,
  :offer_subject, :offer_body,
  :only_companies_with_email,
  {:district_ids => []},
  # {:district_ids => params[:user_setting][:district_ids].try(:keys)},
  :delivery_address,
 )
```

end

See the commented line? In the form above - user_settings_params will not return `:district_ids` array of ids, and this is fine, since I can use the line below instead to have them (got it from guides).

The problem I have is when running this test:

```
test 'should set user level10 districts' do
  user = login_user :paid10

  post :update, :user_setting => {:district_ids => [districts(:zachodniopomorskie).id, districts(:slaskie).id]}

  assert_equal nil, flash[:alert]
  assert_equal 'Preferencje zostały zaktualizowane', flash[:success]


  db_user_districts = User.find(user.id).settings.districts.all
  assert db_user_districts.include? districts(:zachodniopomorskie)
  assert db_user_districts.include? districts(:slaskie)
  assert_equal 2, db_user_districts.count

end
```

It passes. When debugging `user_settings_param` has :district_ids available as if strong parameters were disabled or something. I wanted to submit an issue to rails but most probably I'm doing something wrong and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it - it was because of quirky way I was creating checkboxes for HABTM

```
= check_box_tag "user_setting[district_ids][#{district.id}]", district.id, user.settings.district_ids.include?(district.id)
= label_tag "user_setting[district_ids][#{district.id}]",  district.name
```

For no particular reason I've inserted ids into params keys AND values. And because of that those were passed to `params` object as hash. In test though those were sent as array. So it was the view to blame.

```
= check_box_tag "user_setting[district_ids][]", district.id, user.settings.district_ids.include?(district.id)
= label_tag "user_setting[district_ids][]",  district.name
```